# An item with the same key has already been added. error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

this is my controller class.

```
namespace MvcApplication7.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private rikuEntities db = new rikuEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult create()
        {
            rikuEntities db = new rikuEntities();

            ViewBag.saan = new SelectList(db.emp, "Id", "name");

            return View();


        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult create(login lo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.login.AddObject(lo);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.saan = new SelectList(db.emp, "Id", "name", lo.Id);
            return View(lo);
        }
    }
}
```

this is View
create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>login</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("saan","Select");
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fname)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

actually i have one dropdown list in which values are loaded from table **emp**. 
and one text box. now i want to save these values(drop down selected value and text entered value) in another table login. But whenever i press create button there is a problem is occured "An item with the same key has already been added".

please suggest me what mistake i have done. I have created auto generated ID in both tables. Please suggest me ,its urgent.

Comment: yeah sir you are right... actually i have done some other error...

Comment: I forgot to test another case (that is why i removed my comment), however, tested it some more and found a couple of issues. Can you updated the error you are receiving now?

Comment: yes sir i am receiving now. Thanks alot for caring me.